# How to run Julia function on specific processor using remotecall(), when the function itself does not have return

Tags: function, parallel-processing, julia

I tried to use **remotecall()** in **julia** to distribute work to specific processor. The function I like to run does not have any return but it will output something. I can not make it work as there is no output file after running the code.

This is the test code I am creating:

```
using DelimitedFiles
addprocs(4)    # add 4 processors
@everywhere function test(x)      # Define the function
    print("hi")
    writedlm(string("test",string(x),".csv"), [x], ',')
end
remotecall(test, 2, 2)  # To run the function on process 2
remotecall(test, 3, 3)  # To run the function on process 3
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
Future(3, 1, 67, nothing)
```

And there is no output file (csv), or "hi" shown

I wonder if anyone can help me with this or I did anything wrong. I am fairly new to julia and have never used parallel processing. 
The background is I need to run a big simulation (A big function with bunch of includes, but no direct return outputs) lots of times, and I like to split the work to different processors.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a module function in a worker, you need to import that module locally in that worker first, just like you have to do it in your 'root' process. Therefore your `using DelimitedFiles` directive needs to occur "@everywhere" first, rather than just on the 'root' process. In other words:

```
@everywhere using DelimitedFiles
```

Btw, I am assuming you're using a relatively recent version of Julia and simply forgot to add the `using Distributed` directive in your example.

Furthermore, when you perform a remote call, what you get back is a "Future" object, which is a way of allowing you to obtain the 'future results of that computation' from that worker, once they're finished. To get the results of that 'future computation', use `fetch`.

This is all very simplistic and general information, since you haven't provided a specific example that can be copy / pasted and answered specifically. Have a look at the relevant section in the manual, it's fairly clearly written: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/#Multi-Core-or-Distributed-Processing-1